# Multiple Level of Dependencies in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am very new to makefiles. I have been able to write the script shown below by copying different examples found online. If I am doing something wrong, or not conventional, please point it out.

This is my (working) Makefile for a fortran code I have. The main program stored in `main.f08` calls a module stored in `file1.f08`:

```
FC = gfortran

SRCS: main.f08
OBJS: $(SRCS:.f08=.o)
EXEC: $(SRCS:.f08=)

all: $(EXEC)

file1.o file1.mod: file1.f08
     $(FC) -c $<
     touch $*.o $*.mod

main.o: file1.mod

%.o: %.f08
      $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

main: file1.o

%: %.o
      $(FC) -o MainExe $^

clean:
      rm -f MainExe *.o *.mod
```

I have tried to extrapolate that technique to write a makefile which has a ladder of dependencies. For example, `main.f08` would be calling the module `file1.f08`, which in turn would be calling the module `file2.f08`. Here is what I have so far:

```
FC = gfortran

SRCS: main.f08
OBJS: $(SRCS:.f08=.o)
EXEC: $(SRCS:.f08=)

all: $(EXEC)

file2.o file2.mod: file2.f08
      $(FC) -c $<
      touch $*.o $*.mod    

file1.o: file2.mod

file1.o file1.mod: file1.f08
      $(FC) -c $<
      touch $*.o $*.mod

main.o: file2.mod file1.mod

%.o: %.f08
      $(FC) $(FFLAGS) -c $<

main: file1.o

%: %.o
      $(FC) -o MainExe $^

clean:
      rm -f MainExe *.o *.mod
```

The command line output consist of a few line showing that the code starts compiling the two modules and the main program and then several lines of errors that look like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___brownian_MOD_calcb", referenced from:
  ___integral_MOD_calcint in Integral.o
```

Comment: Can you successfully build the program without a `Makefile`? I.e. by just running compiling each source file and linking them together manually at the command prompt.

Comment: Yes it works, I want to do it via a makefile because I have several modules that depend on one another and my code is only going to get bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working on this and I actually have figured it out.

The `main` executable should be linked to the module's object files in the correct order (an object file should not precede its dependency) followed by its object file, `main.o`. The module's object file should be linked to their dependency (if any) and their `.f08` file. Finally, the `touch` command makes sure that the `.mod` files are up to dates with the `.o` files. Here is the corrected code showed in its simplest version:

```
FC = gfortran

all: main

main  : file2.o file1.o main.o
       $(FC) -o executable file2.o file1.o main.o
main.o: main.f08        
       $(FC) -c main.f08

file2.o  : file2.f08
       $(FC) -c file2.f08
       touch file2.o file2.mod

file1.o  : file2.o file1.f08
       $(FC) -c file1.f08
       touch file1.o file1.mod
```

A more advanced version of the makefile is shown below:

```
FC = gfortran

SRCS = main.f08
SOBJ = $(SRCS:.f08=.o)
EXEC = #(SRCS:.f08=)

FILE = file2.f08 file1.f08
FOBJ = $(SRCS:.f08=.o)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(FOBJ) $(SOBJ)
       $(FC) -o executable $^

%.o: %.f08
       $(FC) -c $<
       touch $*.o $*.mod
```