# In makefiles, how can I compile module files first using automatic variables?

Tags: makefile, fortran

I am new to makefiles. My current makefile looks like this:

```
FC=ifort
FFLAGS=-c -module mod/
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.f90)
OBJECTS=$(addprefix obj/, $(notdir $(SOURCES:.f90=.o)))
EXECUTABLE=RUN

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

obj/%.o: src/%.f90
    $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The problem is my module files have names start with s and p which are usually compiled in the end of the list, and this causes problems when I have some changes in these module files. I am wondering what is the easiest way to compile these module files first? Yes I can change my module file directory to mod/ and set variables:

```
MODULES=$(wildcard mod/*.f90)
MODULE_OBJECTS=$(addprefix obj/, $(notdir $(MODULES: .f90=o)))
```

then add

```
$(MODULE_OBJECTS):$(MODULES)
     $(FC) $(FFLAGS) $< -O $@
```

But, is there other ways to do this?

Comment: This was discussed here before. Did you search Stack Overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran+make

Comment: You may find your answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870392/multiple-level-of-dependencies-in-a-makefile/20883549#20883549